# Why is BUG called in the tasklet_action() function?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

```c
static void tasklet_action(struct softirq_action *a)
{
    // ...

    while (list) {
        struct tasklet_struct *t = list;

        list = list->next;

        if (tasklet_trylock(t)) {
            if (!atomic_read(&t->count)) {
                if (!test_and_clear_bit(TASKLET_STATE_SCHED,
                            &t->state))
                    BUG();

                // ...
    }
}
```

What I understand is that if a tasklet is already scheduled then this code throws a `BUG()`.
Does this mean that the same tasklet cannot run simultaneously, but also could not be scheduled?

Answer (score 7):

That is simply a sanity check on a guaranteed property of tasklets. You can see the properties of a tasklet listed in [a comment in `include/linux/interrupt.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L595):

```
   Properties:
   * If tasklet_schedule() is called, then tasklet is guaranteed
     to be executed on some cpu at least once after this.
   * If the tasklet is already scheduled, but its execution is still not
     started, it will be executed only once.
   * If this tasklet is already running on another CPU (or schedule is called
     from tasklet itself), it is rescheduled for later.
   * Tasklet is strictly serialized wrt itself, but not
     wrt another tasklets. If client needs some intertask synchronization,
     he makes it with spinlocks.
```

By definition, tasklets are guaranteed to run *at least once* after being scheduled. This code:

```c
    if (!atomic_read(&t->count)) {
        if (!test_and_clear_bit(TASKLET_STATE_SCHED,
                    &t->state))
            BUG();
```

Is making sure that this property holds, otherwise there is a bug, and `BUG()` is used to stop execution and cause a runtime panic.

Here's a commented version of the above code, to make it clearer:

```c
    // If the tasklet never ran (t->count == 0)
    if (!atomic_read(&t->count)) {
        // And the tasklet is not scheduled for running (bit TASKLET_STATE_SCHED of t->state is 0)
        if (!test_and_clear_bit(TASKLET_STATE_SCHED,
                    &t->state))
            // There's something wrong, this should never happen!
            BUG();
```

In other words, you cannot have a tasklet around with `t->count == 0` and `t->state & (1<<TASKLET_STATE_SCHED) == 0`. If this happens, there's a bug.